# Widen Windows 10 start menu scrollbar

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I can't find a way to widen Windows 10's start menu scrollbar. Searched Google but no hope. The issue is that so many menu items goes beyond the width and cannot see full name.

For example, I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I just see Microsoft SQL Server 20 only.

Is there any way to do so?

[image: tart]

Comment: See this.....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026164/windows-resize-the-start-menu

Comment: Can you please try this? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/79875-change-size-scroll-bars-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Moab that doesn't seem to be what the OP asked..

Comment: What they asked does not match the image "no way to resize Windows 10's start menu." is very clear but does not match what they want to do in the image which is resize the scrollbar on the start menu.

Comment: @Moab you're right, I did an edit regarding that just now.

Comment: @Moab I saw this, but I don't want this.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @Rauf thank you for the clarification. All i can suggest is a start menu alternative...https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-start-menu-alternatives/